# Typescipt - intersection Types - unique symbol

Tags: typescript, unique, symbols, typescript-typings, intersection

i do not understand how to fill this.

```
export declare type AttributeKey = string & {
  readonly ___attributeKey: unique symbol;
};

const test: AttributeKey = ????
```

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can never satisfy a string literal type that is intersected with anything else.

So you wont be able to assign anything from type `AttributeKey`

EDIT: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9410